# jquery ui tabs selection randomly on basis of checked checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

i am working on module in which i am using jquery ui tabs in first tab i have three check boxes when user select 1st checkbox then the third tab become active same for checkbox 2nd but when user check third checkbox then it activate the 2nd tab only but tthe problem actually occurs when user select two check boxeses at a time like 1st and third or 2nd and third. in these two cases both the tabe 2 and third get active but when user click next step button it moves to 3rd tab but what i want to do is to transfer it to 2nd on first click of next step button and on 2nd click of next step button it shold move to the third tab only in case when two check boxes are checked i.e 1st and 3rd or 2nd and 3rd.for single checkbox when checked its working fine. i already spent a day on it but no luck now need serious help.

this is the jquery for checkbox 1 only as an example complete code is available in jsfiddle below

```
jQuery('#checkbox1').change(function(){ 
  if (this.checked) {
    jQuery('#rdbtns1').fadeIn('slow');

jQuery(function() {

        var $tabs = jQuery('#tabs').tabs();

        jQuery(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(i){

          var totalSize = jQuery(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;

          if (i != totalSize) {
              next = i + 3;
              jQuery(".ui-tabs-panel").append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Next Step</a>");
          }
        });

        jQuery('.next-tab').click(function() { 
               $tabs.tabs('select', $('.next-tab').attr("rel"));
               return false;
           });
    });


   } else {
      jQuery('#rdbtns1').css('display','none').fadeOut('slow');
   }                   
 });
```

here is the http://jsfiddle.net/k2YfP/6/

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes without ability to select multiple of them are called radio buttons. As I see from your JSFiddle, you already are aware of their existance, so I suggest you just use these instead, as this is exactly the scenario what they were designed for.

Comment: can u plz edit my code it will help to understand what you exactly mean

Comment: I'm not sure how I could be any more specific. I'm not doing your homework for you, that's not the way you learn anything from it. As I said, go to your initialize function, and replace `var marker = ...` by `window.myTestMarker = ...` and in your success event, replace all references to the not available, local object `marker` by `window.myTestMarker`. That instruction shouldn't be too complicated. Apply this to all local variables that you need global access to.

Comment: i already learnt alot from it and now need it to be done but i am totally stuck

Comment: Chris i acted upon what u mentioned but no luck just tell me in my logic that where and what change should i made

Comment: as you can see i already did my lot of homework but dont have any idea for multiple check boxes when checked